# How to permanently remove PyCharm Community?

Tags: software-installation

I know that this question has posted few times before but I have a different problem than those one and those answers seem not to work on me. I have installed PyCharm Community 4 few weeks ago, and now I bought a student license (which is free of charge). I now want to install PyCharm Professional by deleting the Community version.

Problem is I don't have a separate directory in which I extracted the PyCharm community. I somehow have managed to install it. When I wrote PyCharm in dash home, I am able to execute the program. But for the professional version, case is different.

When I run the `sudo ./pycharm.sh` it doesn't install like it installed Community version. Every time I run `pycharm.sh` it asks me my license information, which is not permanent. And Professional PyCharm doesn't appear in dash home.

How can I permanently remove Community version and can install professional like I wanted?

Comment: I could solve this by 
```sudo snap remove pycharm-community```                                                                               (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/uninstall.html#snap) as I've installed it via snap. (I could find it out by opening the installation folder in JetBrains Toolbox)

Answer (score 3):

What version of Pycharm you are currently use and version that you want to install? Now let assume it as **Pycharm.x.x.x**:

If you installed it with apt, removed it first.

```
sudo apt-get remove pycharm
```

Delete you old configuration IDE which located at you home folder, you can use `ls -s ~/ | grep pycharm` to find it

```
rm ~/.pycharm.x.x.x
```

Now, if you want to install community edition using Ubuntu Make PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
umake ide pycharm
```

To remove PyCharm installed via umake:

```
umake -r ide pycharm
```

Answer (score 1):

delete the directory `pycharm-community.x.x.x` also the hidden directory .`PyCharm` from the `home` directory

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

I found that this worked well:

```
sudo apt-get purge pycharm-community
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)